# Check if username (Hashed) or email(Hashed) already exist with pdo

Tags: php, pdo, password-hash

I am trying to verify if `username` or `email` are already taken in a registration form, but I can't understand how to do it, since both are hashed in my database with `password_hash()`, how can I compare, users input with the database in pdo? Please explain me the code.

Comment: `$hashedEmail = get_hashed_email_from_database(); if(password_verify($_POST['email'], $hashedEmail)){//they match}` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Incidentally, why are you hashing the email?

Comment: Well… that's why it's not terribly useful to hash the primary account identifier (username/email). At the very least you need to hash it without an individual salt, but that's not really terribly useful either.

Comment: For secure, for example if someone hack my database, the email are "secure"

Comment: Very secure, yes… and useless. You might as well replace it with random garbage for all the good it does you.

Comment: In any case, how can i check if the email alredy exist in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your emails are hashed with a unique salt per hash, there is no way to test for the existence of any one particular email short of testing the needle against *all* hashes in the database. E.g.:

```
foreach ($db->query('SELECT email_hash FROM users') as $user) {
    if (password_verify($_POST['email'], $user['email_hash'])) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

There is no other way, since you cannot recreate the hash without the individual salt, and since you don't know what salt you're looking for you simply have to do them all.

*If* you're going to hash data that you need to search by in the database at all, at the very least it cannot be salted. But if it's not salted, it offers little protection against the scenario you're trying to defend against. Bottom line: hashing data that you need to query by is pretty pointless.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution!

Comment: If you're referring to that PHP snippet: **no, that's a _terrible_ solution,** which I hoped would be self-evident. If you get a few thousand or so users this will become unbearably slow.

Comment: @A.Rossi - You cannot use this example, because the function password_hash() is designed to be slow, what means that with only a few users the request would take seconds only to search for a user.